# How to save pdf file to s3 and on local as well in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, fs

i am stuck in something that i am unable to solve. I am uploading the file and getting it through **req.files**. I have added **middleware** which uploads the file to S3. I tried everything but cannot do it. Upload to **S3** is working fine but it isn't saving the file in local path. When i try through **fs.writeFile** it saves the file which is corrupted.

can someone help me?

**middleware function**

```
 uploadToS3bucket: (path) => {
    return multer(
        {
            storage: multerS3({
                s3: s3,
                acl: 'public-read',
                bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
                contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
                metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
                    cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
                },
                key: function (req, file, cb) {
                    const params = Object.keys(req.params).map(key => {
                        return req.params[key]
                    }).join('/');
                    const key = path + '/' + params + (params.length > 0 ? '/' : '') + shortUUID.generate() + "-" + file.originalname;
                    cb(null, key)
                }
            })
        }
    )
}
```

**route**

```
  router.post('/resume', uploadToS3bucket('temp').fields([
    {name: 'resume', maxCount: 1}
   ]), resumeCtrl.getUserResume);
```

i tried

```
     // in metadata function

   fs.writeFile('python/resume_parser/data/input/resume/' + file.originalname, file, (err) => {
                     if (err) throw err;
                    });
```

and

```
   request({uri: 'http://localhost:3000/v1/user/resume', headers: { 'Content-type' : 'applcation/pdf', 'encoding': 'binary' }} , function (error, response, body) {
                      if (!error) {
                           fs.writeFile("python/resume_parser/data/input/resume/"+ file.originalname, body , function (err) {

                           });
                         }
                     })
```

it is saving the pdf but that is corrupted.
can someone help me?
thanks

Comment: `file` is an object, not the file contents. show the output of `console.log(file)` in metadata, to see if you have a `Buffer` in some property.

Comment: this is what i am getting
{
  fieldname: 'resume',
  originalname: myResume.pdf',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/pdf'
}

Comment: You're saving that to the file, and that's not a PDF. You can't save locally in the `metadata` function.

Comment: how can i save the pdf then any solutions?